# Fill Sub-query using LINQ in EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Friends,

i'm trying to create a `.json` file with an LINQ query using Entity Framework 6:

```
   {
    "id": "1231-12321-sdff-21-31",
    "name": "Product name",
    "description": "Product description"
    "rating": 4.1,
    "price": 7.50,
    "photos": 
    [
     "http://path/photo1.img",
     "http://path/photo2.img"
    ]
}
```

How can i fill the sub-vector `photos`? See my code below:

**My select code**

```
List<ProductViewModel> products = await
    (from prod in db.product
    join prodPhoto in db.product_photo on prod.id equals prodPhoto.product_id
    where prod.id == id
    select new ProductViewModel
    {
        id = prod.id,
        name = prod.name,
        description = prod.description,
        rating = prod.rating,
        price = prod.price,
        photos = new HashSet<ProductPhotoViewModel>()
        {
            new ProductPhotoViewModel
            {
                path = prodPhoto.path
            }
        }
    }).ToListAsync();
```

**My object ProductViewModel**

```
    public class ProductViewModel
    {
    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        photos = new HashSet<ProductPhotoViewModel>();
    }

    //Product
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int? rating { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    //Product photo
    public virtual ICollection<ProductPhotoViewModel> photos { get; set; }
}
```

**and my object ProductImageViewModel**

```
    public class ProductPhotoViewModel
    {
        public string path { get; set; }
    }
```

I know probably my select is wrong, but i can't see what can i do to solve this problem.

**EDIT:**

The EF6 Classes:

**Product**

```
    public partial class product
    {
    public product()
    {
        this.employee_change_product = new HashSet<employee_change_product>();
        this.offer = new HashSet<offer>();
        this.order_has_product = new HashSet<order_has_product>();
        this.product_photo = new HashSet<product_photo>();
        this.product_has_category = new HashSet<product_has_category>();
        this.product_stock = new HashSet<product_stock>();
    }

        public string id { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> rating { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> preparation_time { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string establishment_id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime create_time { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime update_time { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<employee_change_product> employee_change_product { get; set; }
        public virtual establishment establishment { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<offer> offer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<order_has_product> order_has_product { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<product_photo> product_photo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<product_has_category> product_has_category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<product_stock> product_stock { get; set; }
    }
```

**Product Photo**

```
    public partial class product_photo
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> width { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> height { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public string product_id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime create_time { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime update_time { get; set; }

        public virtual product product { get; set; }
    }
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please also show the entity classes.

Comment: @GertArnold Done, my friend.

Comment: AutoMapper was made for this. You have a navigation property `product_photo` so AM, when properly configured, will be able to map `Product` directly onto `ProductViewModel`, including the photos. One off-topic advice: adhere to C# naming conventions.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your answer. Can you give me a example of how to implement this? I have the AutoMapper installed but i can't figure out how to add photos to `photo` :(